# Change my binding Check-Box style when mouse over ListViewItem

Tags: wpf

So i have `ListView` with `Check-Box` cell:

```
<ListView.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxCell">
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListView.Resources>

<ListView.View>
   <GridViewColumn Width="30"  x:Name="gridViewColumnIsChecked" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxCell}"/>
</ListView.View>
```

And i have `ListViewItem` style with several triggers like `IsMouseOver` so when `IsMouseOver` is `True` i am change my `Background color` for example.

So i want to change my `Check-Box` style\color when mouse over `ListViewItem`.

How i can i achieve that ?

Comment: You need a style for your `CheckBox` to look for `ListViewItem`'s `IsSelected` property. You can get that through `DataTrigger`.

Comment: Can i have simple code example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this snippet:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxCell">
        <CheckBox>
            <CheckBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </CheckBox.Style>
        </CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a DataTrigger, which binds to parent ListViewItem.IsMouseOver property, like another answer shows

However, the trigger can be also placed in `<DataTemplate.Triggers>` to make markup shorter. In that case Setter uses TargetName to access the correct control.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxCell">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Name="Chk" />
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Chk" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```